# Isn't user data that comes in from a form in Rails going to be UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

A Rails 3.2 app I'm contributing to has a method that coerces user input to UTF-8.

```
require "iconv"


def normalize(user_input_text)
  Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8').iconv(user_input_text.dup)
end
```

It basically encodes the string in UTF-8 and ignores characters that can't be transcoded.

But isn't all user data that's entering Rails through a form going to be UTF-8 encoded?

In other words, isn't this code specious and unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These resources suggest that indeed you are right.

> Now that the vast majority of web input is UTF-8, we set
>     the inbound parameters to UTF-8. This will eliminate many
>     cases of incompatible encodings between ASCII-8BIT and
>     UTF-8.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/25215d7285db10e2c04d903f251b791342e4dd6a

> Rails 3 solves this very nicely by doing a number of things including interpreting params as UTF-8 and adding workarounds for Internet Explorer

http://jasoncodes.com/posts/ruby19-rails2-encodings